# Set Parent's Height Based On Child's

Tags: html, css, equals

I have a structure that I want to repeat with different content each time. Here's the code (for a Web version of a script):

```
<div id="1_0" class="lineblock"><div class="whosays"><span>CHARACTER:</span></div><div class="whatsaid"><span>Line...</span></div></div>
```

The content of the `<span>` in the `whatsaid` div changes. Sometimes it fill fit on one line; sometimes not.
Using static heights, it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hV1pR.png).

*So, I want to change the height of the `lineblock` div and the `whosays` div based on how tall the `whatsaid` div needs to be.*

Is there a way to do this? Any kind of scripting isn't really an option in this case.
I've tried various combinations of `height:auto` and `height:100%`, but nothing's worked.

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: I assume the id changes as you repeat the line on the top level div?

Comment: @Endophage Yes, it's designed to let me jump to a specific line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graham's links are probably more interesting than what I used here. However, that's works. You can see a demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/uwf8U/1/

Comment: Wow! That's amazing. How does that work with so little markup?

Comment: Actually, I don't really increase the height of the "whosaid" div. I use the background-color of the main container to simulate 2 columns.

Answer (score 1):

The `lineblock` div will expand to the height of whatever content is inside it. That leaves setting the height of the `whatsaid` div as the main challenge.

Essentially what you have here is the classic "CSS Equal height column" problem, which as been discussed in several places. Check out the following links:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail/

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks